# How to align while loop operations and paint event?

Tags: performance, theory, game-physics, mathematical-optimization

I am currently working with painting and displaying on a Cartesian coordinate system. In my game, I have fast moving objects, bullets, for which I use the following formula to determine position:

```
x += speed * Cos(theta);
y += speed * Sin(theta);
```

where **theta** is a `radian` measure and **speed** modifies the speed at the cost of overall continuity. [*lim* speed → ∞] *then* x *and* y = larger "jump" between the starting and next calculated x,y point.

I had to use this formula with a 'high speed' object, so instead of using a timer, which is limited to milisecond .001, I utilized a while loop:

```
while(true) {
  if(currentTime - oldTime > setInterval) //x,y and intersection operations {
   //operations
  } if(currentTime - oldTime > setInterval) //paint operations {
   //operations
  }

  sleep(0,nanoseconds);//sleeps thread or if you're a C kind of guy, "task"
}
```

I want x,y and intersection operations to happen at a much faster rate than the paint event, which I plan to have occur at 30-125 times a second (basically the hertage of a monitor).

**Actual Questions:**

- What would be the most efficient rate for the x,y and intersection operations, so that they would perform at a rate consistent across different CPUs (from a dusty single core @ 1.6 ghz to a fancy shmancy hex-core @ 4.0 ghz)?
- Is there a better angle position formula than mine for these operations?

*note my method of painting the object has nothing to do with my problems, in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a timer fire every time the screen refreshes (60Hz?). In that time you calculate where the object is at this point in time. You draw the object at the determined location.

Whenever you want to find out where the object currently is, you run the physics simulation until time has caught up with the point in time you want to render. This way you get the object being animated in exactly the point in time it should be in.

Define the frequency at which the physics simulation runs. You can pick 60Hz as well or any integer multiple of it. Run the physics engine with the same time increment (which is 1/Frequency). When you want to render, find out how many physics ticks are missing and run them one by one.

This scheme is completely robust against missing or superfluous timer ticks. CPU clock rate does not matter either. The object is always rendered at the price position it should be in.

Comment: Very interesting, I like your style. What would you suggest for calculating the point in time if someone was unable to have the rendering be an event triggered by a screen refresh?

Comment: Any kind of triggering a paining operation would work. A timer, a sleep loop, ... When such an event happens you only need to calculate how much wall-clock time is missing. (Be careful with the computer going to sleep...). GetTickCount64 should allow you to get a continuous time value.

Comment: I'll have to figure out a tick count system as I am using Java instead of C++/C#. I don't believe Java has a tick event or tick variable supplied like the .NET family does. I'll have to synthesize my own.